# Is there a name for the following coding scheme?

Tags: categorical-data

Suppose, that we have a categorical variable say color which can take one of three values: Red, Green and Yellow.

We can code then using dummy coding or effects coding. But, suppose, we were to code it as follows:

```
Red:     1 
Green:   2 
Yellow:  3
```

Leaving aside issues of estimation and interpretation, is there a name for coding categorical variables as above?

Comment: Ordinal? I can't see why you would ever want to do this, unless you have a very strong belief that $R<G<Y$ (or $>$) and that is is exactly linear.

Comment: This is not a coding scheme because it is unable to distinguish clearly among the colors. For instance, it would equate the average of `Red` and `Yellow` with `Green`. It amounts to a kind of (arbitrary) *valuation* of the colors.  Therefore it does not have any standard name.

Comment: @whuber 'It does not have any standard name.' Perhaps, add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would fall under the category of **numerical coding**.

In fact, take a look at this piece of **R** code:

```
colors <- c("Red", "Green", "Yellow")
colors.df <- data.frame(color=sample(colors, size=25, replace=TRUE))
str(colors.df)
```

If you run these lines you'll see that **R** actually *internally* encodes **factors** in the very same way you've described. Crazy!

As suggested in the Comments, there is one important caveat, however: Just because you're using numbers to efficiently represent the values of your categorical variable *does not* mean that you can *treat them* as numbers. In other words, your data remains **categorical** *regardless* of any name changes you may have applied.

Nevertheless, there's nothing inherently wrong with this particular coding scheme. In fact, it's entirely reasonable.

Hope this helps!

**SEE ALSO**: [The numerical coding of information](http://www.jstor.org/stable/41188517) (Swerdlin, 1974)

---

#### Clarification:

Today, it seems as though (at least to me) that the concept of **coding** arises most often in the context of **regression** (for example, as mentioned in the original post, recoding categorical variables as **dummy variables**). However, the notion of **coding systems** is actually much more general than this current usage may suggest, as indicated by its entry in Dover's [Outline of Basic Statistics: Dictionary and Formulas](http://store.doverpublications.com/048647769x.html):

```
Coding System - In information theory, any consistent scheme used to represent
  a given set of data. A coding system is usually employed either to reduce 
  error or increase efficiency in the transmission of information.
```

According to this standard, it is clear that the simple *mapping* of colors to integers as described in the original post would, indeed, qualify as a coding scheme. Other than merely reducing the size of the data being stored (since, for example, the vector `c("Green", "Green", "Yellow", "Red")` could now be stored more compactly as `c(2,2,3,1)`), there does not appear to be much benefit to this specific scheme, however. Nevertheless, *it still qualifies as a coding system*.

Now, to elaborate on the "**important caveat**" mentioned above (in my original answer), this particular coding scheme is *very misleading* within the regression setting. In fact, in its entry for "**Dummy Variable**", the [Cambridge Dictionary of Statistics](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/statistics-probability/statistics-and-probability-general-interest/cambridge-dictionary-statistics-2nd-edition) indicates the importance of *re*-coding (via Dummy Variables) such *numerical codes* when in the regression setting:

```
"Such recoding is used before polychotomous variables are used as
explanatory variables in a regression analysis to avoid the unreasonable
assumption that the original numerical codes for the categories, i.e. the
values 1,2,...,k, correspond to an interval scale."
```

Thus, it's not that this system of coding is *meaningless*, per se, within the regression setting; rather, the misspecification is due to attributing more meaning to these *numerical codes* than would otherwise be warranted. Make sense?

Hope this clarifies my original answer!

Comment: You are confusing *encoding* with *naming* of factors. The encoding for a trivariate factor requires two-dimensional *vectors* and this is what `R` uses under the hood.  It definitely does not use the numbers $1,2,3$ to *encode* these three strings.

Comment: From [CRAN](http://bit.ly/1jNsSc7): `Factors are currently implemented using an integer array to specify the actual levels and a second array of names that are mapped to the integers.` It's the *coding system* represented here--the mapping of the names to integers--that I am referring to.

Comment: I believe you misunderstand the meaning of "integer array." It does not refer to the array `c(1,2,3)` as your answer suggests.  It instead refers to using a *vector* for each distinct factor. These vectors appear within the rows of the model matrix. You can see them with `x <- factor(c("red","green","yellow")); model.matrix(~x)`. The factor *names* are "1", "2", and "3" while their *encodings* are $(1,1,0)$, $(1,0,0)$, and $(1,0,1)$, respectively. The map is from names to vectors rather than integers. The closest Swerdlin gets to this is his fertilizer example which distinguishes N, P, and K.

Comment: No, that's just it--by creating a **design matrix** you are actually **re-coding** the coded numerical data in order to make it suitable for regression. As described in the [Cambridge Dictionary of Statistics](http://bit.ly/1r3BrQq): `"Such recoding is used before *polychotomous* variables are used as explanatory variables in a regression analysis to avoid the unreasonable assumption that the original numerical codes for the categories, i.e. the values 1,2,...,k, correspond to an *interval* scale."`

Comment: In other words, you have the **categories** (e.g. "Red", "Green", "Yellow"), you have the **original numerical codes** for the categories (e.g. 1,2,3), and *then* (assuming you want to be able to run a regression) you *re-code* with the k-1 dummy variables, etc.

Comment: If you would make your case--and display these distinctions--in the answer itself, Steve, it would be greatly improved (and I would be glad then to upvote it). I am concerned that in its present form it is too easy to misunderstand. Consider, too, the implication from the wording of the question that we are in a regression setting. We don't want the OP (or anyone else) to leave with the impression that the assignment of integers $1,2,3$ to three categories is an adequate and full representation of those data for regression purposes.

Comment: That must be the root of our misunderstanding: The wording of the question question gave me the impression that we *weren't* in the regression setting... Anyway, thanks for the feedback.